# How to diff hierarchical-data?

Tags: diff, hierarchical-data

Are there any tools which diff hierarchies?

IE, consider the following hierarchy:

```
A has child B.
B has child C.
```

which is compared to:

```
A has child B.
A has child C.
```

I would like a tool that shows that C has moved from a child of B to a child of A.  Do any such utilities exist?  If there are no specific tools, I'm not opposed to writing my own, so what are some good algorithms which are applicable to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

A great general resource for diffing hierarchies (not specifically XML, HTML, etc) is the [Hierarchical-Diff](https://github.com/gabriel-weaver/Hierarchical-Diff) github project based on a bit of Dartmouth research. They have a pretty extensive list of [related work](https://github.com/gabriel-weaver/Hierarchical-Diff/issues?labels=Related%20Work&sort=created&direction=asc&state=open) ranging from XML diffing, to configuration file diffing to HTML diffing.

In general, actually performing diffs/patches on tree structures is a fairly well-solved problem, but displaying those diffs in a manner that makes sense to humans is still the wild west. That's double true when your data structure already has some semantic meaning like with HTML.

Comment: When I look at your Hierarchical-Diff on git hub all I see for the code is a README.txt which says "Hello World!"; I didn't find any other code.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider our [SmartDifferencer](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer) tools.

These tools compare computer source code files in a diff-like way.  Unlike diff, which is line oriented, these tools see changes according to code structure (variable name, expression, statement, block, function, class, etc.) as plausible edits ("move, insert, delete, replace, copy, rename"), producing answers that makes sense to programmers.

These computer source codes have exactly the "hierarchy" structure you are suggesting; the various constructs nest.  Specifically to your topic, typically code blocks can nest inside code blocks.    The SmartDifferencer tools use target-language accurate parsers to "deconstruct" the source text into these hierarchical entities.  We have a Smart Differencer for XML in which you can obviously write nested tags.

The answer isn't reported as "Nth child of M has moved" although it is actually computed that way, by operating on the parse trees produced by the parsers.  Rather it is reported as "code fragment of type  at line x col y to line a col b has moved/..."

Answer (score -1):

The answer my good sir is: [Depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), also known as Depth-first traversal. You might find some use of the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

You can't swing a dead cat without hitting some sort of implementation for this when dealing with comparing XML trees. Take a gander at [diffxml](http://diffxml.sourceforge.net/) for an example.